# Declare a variable per thread and manage them in c# Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I'm writing a code to iterate through a huge list of objects in order to persist them in DB.

I have a counter wich is increasing with each iteration and when it reaches 500 I persist all in DB (from a StringBuilder).

If I do it sequential I have no problems, but it takes a long time. That's why I want to do it with parallelism.

With parallelism I've seen I cannot have one StringBuilder for all threads, so I need to create one for each thread.

My questions are:
How can I create a StringBuilder per thread?
And then, How can I persist all StringBuilder objects to DB and empty them all when the static counter reaches 500 loops?

I have the following code:

```
int counter = 0;

Parallel.ForEach(myList, element =>
{
    lock (balanceLock)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder(); //I need one StringBuilder for thread, not for iteration
    
    ...
    
    if (decimal.Remainder(counter, 500) == 0)
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            persistInDB(sb.toString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
});
```

Comment: There's no point in using `Parallel.ForEach` if you use locks inside it. That method is meant for data parallelism - working with large amounts of local, in-memory data. Not general purpose parallel execution, and definitely not for executing remote database calls

Comment: What are you trying to do? You described what you think the solution would look like, not what the actual problem is. `huge list` would be eg 1M in-memory objects. 100K would be lots.  500 is a tiny amount of data. You can insert all those rows with a single INSERT command, or use eg SqlBulkCopy to insert the data in a single bulk operation using minimal logging

Comment: I would like to point out that when using tasks it's the system that's deciding when it's doing his work to another thread.

Comment: If you have a large collection you want to send to the database you can use [FastMember's ObjectReader together with SqlBulkCopy](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) to insert the data to the database.

Comment: The point is that I can have up to 10M items on the list in memory and each one generates a different query on the DB. That's why parallel processing

Comment: @Dalamar And everyone else's point is that you should *avoid performing so many queries in the first place* and instead perform fewer queries that do more.

Comment: FYI, there is a remainder operator you can use: `if (counter % 500 == 0)`

Comment: @Servy And how can I do that if each element of the list generate a different query? That's why I use a StringBuilder with all the queries and then I execute them against DB

Comment: @RufusL I know that operator thx

Comment: @Dalamar If you're inserting records, you use a bulk copy as others have said, if you're querying records rather than inserting you alter the query such that it returns all of the data needed for all of the records, how you'd do that would depend on the specifics of what you're doing, which we can't know.

Comment: @Servy Then, can you give me an example of bulk insert please?

Comment: @Dalamar https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+bulk+insert

Comment: @Servy But Is there a way to bulk insert multiple INSERT statements? like: 
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(a,b,c)
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(a1,b1,c1)
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(a2,b2,c2)

Comment: @Dalamar That's literally the whole point of buik insert, to insert multiple records in a single statement.

Comment: @Dalamar what you describe isn't parallel *data* processing so `Parallel.ForEach` is completely inappropriate. You *have* to explain what all those things do for people to help. And most likely, the answer would have nothing to do with parallelism. Companies use ETL to load millions of rows into data warehouses for decades, without requiring parallel processing. It's far easier and *faster8 to eg load the data into staging tables and process them using SQL queries. The latency of 5M individual connections and commands is far larger than the time needed to load and process 5M items

Comment: @Dalamar as for examples of bulk insert, I already posted a link to FastMember that would allow you to insert those 5M items with 5 lines of code. It would be even faster if you *didn't* load the data in memory but had a way to load them in a stream, eg with an `IEnumerable`. Copying big files to the database and loading them with bulk import commands is even faster

Comment: If you insist on your approach then note that building strings most likely doesn't need to be parallelized, because it's already very fast. Slow part is executing those queries against database, so parallelize only that (and not with Parallel.ForEach, because it's IO operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it in a sequential way, by putting the records in a table and making a SqlBulkCopy against the DB, following the advices.

```
DataTable table = getDataTable();

myList.ForEach(element => {
    
    //...
    
    table.Rows.Add(getRow(element));

    if (decimal.Remainder(counter, 500) == 0){
        SqlConnection _db;
        _db.Open();
        
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_db)){
            var map1 = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("columnName1", "columnName1");
            var map2 = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("columnName2", "columnName2");
            //...
            
            bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(map1);
            bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(map2);
            //...
            
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTableName";
            bulk.WriteToServer(table);

            bulk.Close();
        }
    }
}
```